# How do I load the node create or edit form?

Tags: forms, 8

To load the login form I am using the following code.

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm');
```

I would like to load the form to create or edit a node. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Copying partially from an answer that I gave here: [How to alter $form_state before render a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199383/how-to-set-field-values-of-a-form-before-rendering-it-from-a-controller)

To get an add form, you can have to do something like this:

```
$values = array('type' => $node_type);

$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->create($values);

$form = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getFormObject('node', 'default')
  ->setEntity($node);
return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
```

Edit: Somehow I missed that you said edit. You do exactly the same then, except that you don't create a new $node, you load the one you want to edit and then use that.

As written there, this is based on the entityblock_form module, so if you need this in a block, you can also just use that module.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have implemented same for profile form, it works, Along with address fields I have the country, stage fields, which is an Ajax enabled. form alter is disturbing on ajax call, I want to call a function on #after_build, but it's not invoking. please help

Comment: If you are in a controller, there's an easier way to get the node add form.  After creating the new node object as in Berdir's code above, you can simply use:

    $form_render_array = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($node);

Comment: Awesome hint, kudos to Berdir

Comment: Just to be clear, the above should be done in the Controller. I tried to do it extending FormBase for way too long.

Comment: +1 doing it via controller I am able to load the form just fine, thank you!